# Windows 2008 Enterprise Windows Update does not update and it does not error

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-update

I have a Virtual Windows 2008 Enterprise server. When i go to Windows Update it says No new updates are available for your computer but i DO believe it is not actually checking for updates. When i click on Check For Updates, in other servers it does like a 1-2 seconds checking ( you can see the progress bar bouncing ) but this 4 servers (the only ones with 32 bits, rest are 64bits and they all update like a charm.) takes about a quarter of a second or less. it's just impossible that in such a short time it actually connects.

One more thing is it has no history of updates... you know that's impossible with windows products. Brand new installations already needs updates... I can see a long, up to 30 items, in the 64bits server.

This is frustrating since we cant do much in our servers without getting errors and crazyness. Specially trying to get .net 4.0 to work.

Please, some help on this?

Comment: Do you have WSUS configured in your environment? BTW: .Net 4.0 seems to break a lot of things.

Comment: We have one server 2008 R2 with that Role (or Feature, cant remember) activated. But i havent "told" any computer to go look for updates at this server. is this automatically activated? other servers would detect it automatically? why does the rest of the servers communicate to Windows Update, but only these 4 would not?

Answer (score 1):

if you can ping your patching server (windowsupdate.microsoft.com if not an internal WSUS server or similar), run:

```
sc stop wuauserv
sc start wuauserv
```

Then check for updates again.

If this doesn't work, give more information on where patches are coming from.  WSUS troubleshooting is different from the web.

-Waldo

Comment: Well, this is getting interesting. From web001 to web004 I cant ping windowsupdate.microsoft.com, but i can ping google.com or any other site. That's the first issue. Now, I got to work WSUS in our domain. All desk computers (Windows 7) are connecting perfectly fine BUT 3 out of 4 servers (win2k8 32 bits) are not. I already executed from command prompt wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow and it worked for web004 only. It seems to me EXTREMELLY WEIRD that in my WSUS Console i have had to approve all kind of updates for all kind of operating systems we have, EXCEPT FOR Win2k8 Enterprise.

Comment: It is suspicious to me that Windows 2008 Enterprise (those 4 web servers) does not need any kind of updates.

Comment: First, do those servers that can't ping Windows Update, can they ping?  If so, do a traceroute to see where the cutoff is.  Sounds like you either have a name resolution issue or a routing issue.

On your WSUS server, ensure that you have a 2k8ENT server checked in; if there aren't any checked in, I don't think that updates will display.  (I'm don't have access to a WSUS server right now...)